# Прошу помочь с объяснением постановки запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Да, счастье, у кого есть эдакий сынок!"
Цитата взята из "Горе от Ума". Почему "счастье" выделяется запятыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не *счастье* выделяется запятыми, а отделяются ими:

1. С одной стороны — утвердительное слово *да*:

> Слова *да* и *нет*, выражающие утверждение и отрицание, выделяются запятыми...
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129

2. С другой стороны — придаточное предложение (изъяснительное), раскрывающее смысл главной части (т. е. разъясняющее, в чём именно заключается упомянутое счастье).

Comment: Егор, уточните, пожалуйста.  Насколько нормативно это изъяснительное предложение, если об этом не сразу можно догадаться?  Есть ли  здесь стилевые  и структурные особенности?

Comment: Sharon, включите своё хорошее воображение :)

Comment: Счастье, у кого есть воображение :) А кстати, можно ли так говорить? Поясните, пжста .

Comment: @Sharon, думаю, что можно. Заметил, что в обоих случаях перед изъяснительным придаточным подразумевается слово "тем". Если его добавить, то причина постановки запятой, на мой взгляд, очевидна.

Comment: Все верно! Я всего лишь хотела сказать следующее. Если опорным словом в изъяснительном придаточном является существительное, а не глагол, то надо быть внимательным к указательному слову (можно ли его опустить или нет). У Грибоедова смысл фразы хорошо понимается, но это разговорный стиль, характерный для комедии. А иногда предложение сложно понять, тогда наличие указательного слова желательно. А ответ у Егора в целом правильный.

Comment: «Думаю, что можно» — мы с Грибоедовым и Пушкиным тоже думаем, что можно. В том же «Горе от ума» есть: «Блажен, кто верует». В ЕО — «Блажен, кто смолоду был молод», — это только навскидку. Возможно, когда-то такая конструкция была популярнее, чем с местоименным прилагательным. Кстати... «Перед изъяснительным придаточным подразумевается слово "тем"» — у Грибоедова в топикстартовой цитате может подразумеваться и слово «тому». «Если его добавить, то причина постановки запятой, на мой взгляд, очевидна» — ну, она и без этого совершенно очевидна.